# WPF - custom control set fill to rectangle

Tags: wpf

i have custom control Icon, which contains from rectangle. I setup Fill default to parent value. But sometimes i would like set fill to any color. I dont want create DependencyProperty for Fill. Is the alternative?
This is my code:

**Icon control:**

```
<UserControl>
    <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12" 
               Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}, AncestorLevel=3}}">
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{Binding Path=Picture, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Icon}}}" />
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    </Rectangle>
</UserControl>



public partial class Icon
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PictureProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register("Picture", typeof(Canvas), typeof(Icon));

        public Canvas Picture
        {
            get { return (Canvas)GetValue(PictureProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PictureProperty, value); }
        }

        public Icon()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

**Usage**
This works:

```
<controls:Icon Picture="{StaticResource appbar_calendar}"/>
```

This would also like:

```
<controls:Icon Picture="{StaticResource appbar_calendar}" Fill="Yellow"/>
```

I would like both options.
Thanks

Comment: it seems you're using Foreground value in ControlTemplate, so <controls:Icon Picture="{StaticResource appbar_calendar}" Foreground="Yellow"/> will work as expected.

Comment: Just some nitpicking: custom control and `UserControl` are different concepts. If you find yourself writing a `ControlTemplate` for a `UserControl` you might be better off to create an actual custom control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a UserControl has no Fill property you could use its Background property to fill the Rectangle:

**Icon.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Icon"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="uc">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12" 
                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{Binding Path=Picture, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Icon}}}" />
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

**Icon.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class Icon : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PictureProperty
         = DependencyProperty.Register("Picture", typeof(Canvas), typeof(Icon));

    public Canvas Picture
    {
        get { return (Canvas)GetValue(PictureProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PictureProperty, value); }
    }

    public Icon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Window.xaml:**

```
<controls:Icon Picture="{StaticResource appbar_calendar}" Background="Yellow"/>
```

This is the alternative. If you truly want a Fill property you will of course have to define another dependency property called "Fill" in your custom Icon class.